# Logistic growth

Tags: calculus

The rate at which a population grows dP/dt is $0.3P/((5)(5-P/500))$.

The initial population is 2 at time = 0

I solved the problem to get P(t) = $2500/(1+1248e^-.3t). by integrating the integral and separation of variables

When will the population = 1000?

Is that where P(t) = 1000?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the problem correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

As Amzoti commented, there is probably typo's in the equation.

Assuming that you obtained the right solution, I must suppose that it should be $$P(t)=\frac{2500}{1+1249 e^{-3 t/10}}$$ in order to fulfill the condition $P(0)=2$ (not $1248$ since $e^0=1$).

Now you look for the time at which population will be $1000$; this means that your search $t$ such that $P(t)=1000$. So, you have $$1000=\frac{2500}{1+1249 e^{-3 t/10}}$$ Take the reverse of both sides, isolate the exponential term and take the logarithms of both sides. You should end with $$t=\frac{10}{3} \log \left(\frac{2498}{3}\right)\approx 22.4154$$